# Passing an array from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to pass an array through a function in a controller class and retrieve it from another function in a class inside model, but the values cannot be retrieved. please advise.

The code is as follows.

Controller class code

```
 class home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

function index() {
    $this->load->view('loginview');
}

function login() {
    $parameters = array(
        '$uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        '$passwords' => $this->input->post('password')
    );

    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    $validate = $this->loginModel->validateuser($parameters);

    if(count($validate)== 1){
        echo "Logged in";
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect('home/index');
        echo "dasad";
    }


}
```

}

Model class code

```
class loginModel extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function validateuser($parameters) {

        $uname = $parameters['uname'];
        $pass = sha1($mem['pass']);



    $query = $this->db->query("select * from user where username = '$uname' and password = '$pass'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;

}
```

}

The variables $uname and $pass are the two values that need to get to query the database. please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass an array from controller to model in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049554/pass-an-array-from-controller-to-model-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

There are errors in your code. Correct ones of controller login() method:

```
function login() {

    // you don't need '$' sign
    $parameters = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        'pass' => $this->input->post('password')
    );

    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    $validate = $this->loginModel->validateuser($parameters);

    // stuff..

}
```

and model loginModel() method:

```
public function validateuser($parameters) {

    $uname = $parameters['name'];
    $pass = sha1($parameters['pass']); // and second error was here

    // stuff..

}
```

Comment: owh.... ya thanks a lot i have used $ in array keys in the controller that s the biggest problem thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Your array key strings are different in model and controller classes. Here are the possible fixes.

In Controller use this:

```
$parameters = array(
        'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        'passwords' => $this->input->post('password')
    );
```

Secondly in your Model. Use this to get parameters.

```
  $uname = $parameters['uname'];
  $pass = sha1($parameters['passwords']);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't matter with the way the variables are being passed.

Comment: yes, using $ in array keys was the biggest problem and ya it was nt matching as well thanks a lot for the help....

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer is already fixed but i just want to give you an alternative of doing it. It is more secure and short:

Controller:

```
function login() {

    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    $validate = $this->loginModel->validateuser();

    if($validate ){
        echo "Valid User";
    } else{
        echo "Invalid User";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function validateuser() {

 $query = $this->db->query("select * from user where username = ? and password = ?",array($this->input->post('uname'),sha1($this->input->post('password'))));
   if($query->num_rows() == 1){
      return true;
   }else{
     return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: yes, it was solved. looks like your methods is better from what i have done... thanks alot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only way to do this I found obviously was to json_encode() the array in the controller and json_decode them in the model. IT worked like a charm form me.
Good luck!