# Pass an array from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am doing a project in Codeigniter. Here I fetch the latest 10 mails from my gmail id using imap.Here I want to take the from field of fetched mail and i want to check whether the from field of fetched mail is in my database `table('clients')`. Here I stored the 10 from field of fetched mail to array and passed it to model,where the checking is takingplace and returns the matching field name. But it is not working for me.

My controller function is:

```
if ($mbox = imap_open($authhost, $user, $pass)) {
                $emails = imap_search($mbox, 'ALL');
                $some = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "Suspicious sign in prevented"', SE_UID);
                $MC = imap_check($mbox);
                $inbox = $MC->Nmsgs;
                $inboxs = $inbox - 9;
                if ($emails) {
                    $data['overview'] = imap_fetch_overview($mbox, "$inboxs,$inboxs:$inbox", 0);
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($data['overview'] as $i => $val) {

                        $from[$i] = $val->from;
                        $i++;
                    }

                    $data['result'] = $this->crm_model->get_names($from);
                    foreach ($data['result'] as $row) {
                        echo $row->name;echo "<br/>";
                    }

                }
                imap_close($mbox);
            }
```

And my model function is:

```
function get_names($from) {

    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('clients');
    $this->db->where_in('name', $from);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

But when I used the above model function like below, it returns the value

```
function get_names() {
                  $options = array(
                         '0' => 'Job Openings',
                         '1' => 'Offers',
                         '2' => 'Techgig',
                         '3' => 'Australia',
                        );

        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('clients');
        $this->db->where_in('name', $options);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

I think the problem is with passing value from controller to model. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: try by printing $query->result_array() in model itself!

Comment: @sandip  I tested $query->result_array() and echo the result there.not returing any value an empty page only

Comment: wait a minute you echoed it & it displayed empty array() right?

Comment: try by print_r() it prints array

Comment: @sandip  I tried foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) { echo $row['name']; } in model it returns nothing.an empty page.

Answer (score 2):

While executing any query in database using where_in (list of comma separated values),
the list of values should be like this array:

```
$options = array('Hello', 'World!', 'Beautiful', 'Day!');
```

Not like this:

```
 $options = array('0' => 'Job Openings','1' => 'Offers','2' => 'Techgig','3' =>'Australia',);
```

to do this you should implode this array!

```
$opt=implode(",",$options);
```

and pass this $opt array to WHERE_IN()

Hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: When i tried using imploded array , it will not return anything.empty screen only.

Comment: No.When I used the array $options = array('0' => 'Job Openings','1' => 'Offers','2' => 'Techgig','3' =>'Australia',); it returns the result.When i implode the same array like this Job Openings,Offers,Techgig,Australia.and pass the imploded array to where_in clause it will not return value.

Comment: `implode()` converts your array into a string.. You cannot pass string to `where_in()`.. So this method fails

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `$i`..

```
if ($emails) {
                $data['overview'] = imap_fetch_overview($mbox, "$inboxs,$inboxs:$inbox", 0);
               // $i = 0;
                foreach ($data['overview'] as $val) {

                    $from[] = $val->from;
                    //$i++;
                }

                $data['result'] = $this->crm_model->get_names($from);
                foreach ($data['result'] as $row) {
                    echo $row->name;echo "<br/>";
                }

            }
```

Do these changes and check

Comment: I have checked with your suggestion.But not returning any value.empty page only.

Comment: @Balu Okay now you are storing the `$val->from` in `$from[]` right.. `print_r($from)` after the foreach loop in your controller and check what you get

Comment: @Balu If everything is fine there, `print_r($from)` in your model function and check your data.. If that is also fine,then the empty page you are getting would be a database issue

Comment: I got an array like this  Array ( [0] => "Anitha (HR)" [1] => Techgig [2] => Govt Jobs [3] => Techgig ....) when using print_r($from) in both controller and model.

Comment: But when i use an array like                   $options = array( '0' => 'Job Openings', '1' => 'Offers', '2' => 'Techgig'); it returns value.

Comment: @Balu Well,then you don't have any rows with those names i guess.. Can you tell me what output did you get when you use `$options`?

Comment: my options array is $options = array('0' => 'JobOpenings','1' => 'Offers','2' => 'Techgig','3' => 'Australia',);.And my table clients name field contains values: Offers,Job Openings,Freshers Live,Testing. The result what i got is Offers
Job Openings.

Comment: @Balu Then the output which you are getting when you use `$from` is perfect.. You don't get the output because you don't have the names similar to that in your `$from` array

Comment: I have given only 3 values from my $from array.The complete values are Array ( [0] => Offers [1] => "Snapdeal.com" [2] => Freshers Live [3] => "Naukri.com Jobs" [4] => Job Openings [5] => Fresherslive [6] => Offers [7] => "Anitha (HR)" [8] => Techgig [9] => Techgig ).